# Integral of $\ln |\sin(x)|$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, integration, special-functions

Does anyone have a real formula for the integral $$\int\ln |\sin(x)|\,dx ?$$
Neither Maple nor Mathematica give a real answer.

Using integration by parts and the series for $x\cot x$, I get $$x\ln |\sin(x)|-\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{2^{2k}B_{2k}}{(2k+1)!}x^{2k+1}+C$$
where $B_{2k}$ are Bernoulli numbers. Does anyone recognize this function?

Comment: The usual way would be to break into intervals, where $\sin x > 0$ and where $\sin x < 0$.

Comment: [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net) gives an answer that involves complex numbers. What is the problem?

Comment: In case it helps, *without absolute value*, [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+log%28sin%28x%29%29) gives an answer using polylogarithm.

Comment: @arbautjc has the answer, more or less. Remember that $\log|\sin\,x|$ is $\pi$-periodic, so take the integral expression across $(0,\pi)$ and add a step function.

Comment: But it is in complex form.

Comment: The polylogarithm of complex argument can be re-expressed in terms of the Clausen functions or the inverse tangent integrals.

Answer (score 3):

We have $\vert \sin(x) \vert = \left(1-\cos^2(x)\right)^{1/2}$. Hence, we have have
$$\ln \vert \sin(x) \vert = \dfrac12 \ln \left(1-\cos^2(x)\right) = -\dfrac12 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos^{2k}(x)}k$$
Now $$\int \cos^{2k}(x) dx = a(x) \cdot \dfrac{\cos^{2k+1}(x)}{2k+1} \cdot F^1_2(1/2,k+1/2,k+3/2,\cos^2(x))$$
where $a(x) = \begin{cases} -1 & \text{if }x \pmod {2\pi} \in [0, \pi)\\ +1 & \text{if }x \pmod{2 \pi} \in [\pi, 2\pi)\end{cases}$ and $F_2^1$ is the hypergeometric function defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Hence, we get that
$$\int \ln \vert \sin(x) \vert = -\dfrac{a(x)}2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos^{2k+1}(x)}{k(2k+1)}F^1_2(1/2,k+1/2,k+3/2,\cos^2(x)) + \text{constant}$$
which is probably a useless result.

Comment: "...which is probably a useless result." LOL

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Whenever I see the hypergeometric function appearing, I regard it to be useless :), probably because I never get to interact with them often.

Comment: Note that this indefinite integral is discontinuous.  A continuous one would not be periodic.